# Error when calling qExec "no known conversion for argument 1 to QObject"

Tags: c++, qt, testing, qobject, qttest

I'm trying to create tests for a c++ application with QtTest. The three relevent files that I have are: `GuiTests.cpp` which contains my main function, `testsuite1.cpp` which contains my tests and `testsuite1.h` which contains the definitions of my tests. I created these files with help from different guides, for example [this one](http://xilexio.org/?p=125).

When I try to build I get this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'qExec(TestSuite1 (*)(), int&, char**&)'

no known conversion for argument 1 from 'TestSuite1 (*)()' to 'QObject*'
```

I don't understand why, as you can see in `testsuite.h` below `TestSuite1` is a `QObject`. The funny thing is this exact code (I am pretty sure) worked before but then I fiddled around with passing `argc` and `argv` to `guiTest()` for a while, and after I removed `argc` and `argv` and went back to what I had before (what I currently have, please see the files below) I got this error.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time and I can't find any answers online, so please help me, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

GuiTests.cpp

```
#include "testsuite1.h"
#include <QtTest>
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TestSuite1 testSuite1();
    return QTest::qExec(&testSuite1, argc, argv);
}
```

testsuite1.h

```
#ifndef TESTSUIT1_H
#define TESTSUIT1_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtTest>

class TestSuite1 : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestSuite1();
    ~TestSuite1();

private slots:
    // functions executed by QtTest before and after test suite
    void initTestCase();
    void cleanupTestCase();

    // functions executed by QtTest before and after each test
    //void init();
    //void cleanup();

    // test functions
    void testSomething();
    void guiTest();
};

#endif // TESTSUIT1_H
```

testsuite1.cpp

```
#include "testsuite1.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtTest>

TestSuite1::TestSuite1()
{

}

TestSuite1::~TestSuite1()
{

}

void TestSuite1::initTestCase()
{

}

void TestSuite1::cleanupTestCase()
{

}

void TestSuite1::guiTest()
{
    QVERIFY(1+1 == 2);
}

void TestSuite1::testSomething()
{
    QLineEdit lineEdit;

    QTest::keyClicks(&lineEdit, "hello world");

    QCOMPARE(lineEdit.text(), QString("hello world"));

    //QVERIFY(1+1 == 2);
}

//QTEST_MAIN(TestSuite1)
//#include "TestSuite1.moc"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TestSuite1 testSuite1();
```

declares a function named `testSuite1` returning `TestSuite1`. Taking address of it gives you `TestSuite1 (*)()` (a function pointer) instead of `TestSuite1*` that would convert to `QObject*`.

Use one of the following:

```
TestSuite1 testSuite1;
TestSuite1 testSuite1{};
auto testSuite1 = TestSuite();
auto testSuite1 = TestSuite{};
```

to declare a variable.

Comment: Ah! I knew it was going to be something silly like this. Thanks a lot mate!